# GCP Dataflow API is not enabled despite enabling it

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

So I was trying the in-console tutorial of Dataflow. It asks me to enable API which I did. Now while I was in middle of tutorial, in one of the steps I ran into this:

> "error": {
>       "code": 400,
>       "message": "(aa368f39ee923d7e): Dataflow API is not enabled. Please use the Cloud Platform Console,
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/dataflow.googleapis.com/overview?project=nextwordprediction,
>   to enable Dataflow API.",
>       "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"   }

I check in my "APIs & Services" and API is enabled. I also thought of disabling and enabling again but when I try to disable it, it again says precondition failed. Now I m just stuck.

Comment: Hi Ravish, sometimes the APIs can take a little bit to enable. Have you tried again? Also, how did you enable the APIs? What language are you using? Did you take any actions outside of the guided tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if all the below API's are enabled in the project

```
Compute Engine API
Dataflow API
Cloud Resource Manager API
Cloud Logging API
Cloud Storage
Google Cloud Storage JSON API
BigQuery API
Cloud Pub/Sub API
```